# How to switch to other fragment in different back stack using Navigation Component?

Tags: android, navigation, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I have 3 bottom navigation tabs called `Home, Dashboard, Profile`.

- In `Home`, I have `Fragment1` and `Fragment2`,
- In `Dashboard`, I have `Fragment3` and `Fragment4`
- And in `Profile`, I have `MyProfile` and `EditProfile`.

Now, in `Fragment2`, a button `changeAvatar` can open `EditProfile` in stack `Profile`. Because `EditProfile` should be in tab `Profile`, so if I don't want to include `EditProfile` into `navGraph` of `Home`, how can I achieve that behavior?

Comment: I could not understand,  you want fragment 6 to load, in navigation A or C?

Comment: @notTdar sorry, I edited for more readable.

Comment: Do you have 3 nav_graphs? Why not using 1 Activity with 1 nav_graph which has all 6 fragments as possible destinations?

Comment: @muetzenflo yes, exactly using 3 nav_graphs with same as [`NavigationAdvanceSample`](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample) . How can I use 1 nav_graph if I use `BottomNavigationView` ? each stack should keep its top fragment when I came back.

Comment: ah, i see. Didnt get this requirement. Sorry, another question: Why do you not want to use EditProfile in the Home-nav_graph. If you use the ViewModel approach from Jetpack, it should be no problem to use EditProfile as "third" navigation destination in `Home`. You can use 1 nav_graph, if the BottomNavigation is part of the activity which holds the navHostFragment.

Comment: No, you can't use 1 nav_graph because only the top fragment in a back stack is kept, all other fragment will be destroyed (view) state. Suppose from `Home`, I go to `Fragment1, 2` (or deeper like go to detail, detail...), switch to tab `Dashboard`, I go to `Fragment3,4,5`... then I select the `Home` tab, `Fragment2` must be shown .

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is known as [global action](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-global-action).

Given you have the following `nav_graph` structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/main_nav_graph"
            app:startDestination="@id/actionHome">

    <navigation
            android:id="@+id/actionHome"
            android:label="Home"
            app:startDestination="@id/fragment1">
        <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment1"
                android:name="com.example.app.Fragment1"
                android:label="Home Fragment 1"
                tools:layout="@layout/fragment_1" />
        <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment2"
                android:name="com.example.app.Fragment2"
                android:label="Home Fragment 2"
                tools:layout="@layout/fragment_2" />

    </navigation>

    <navigation
            android:id="@+id/actionDashboard"
            android:label="Dashboard"
            app:startDestination="@id/fragment3">
        <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment3"
                android:name="com.example.app.Fragment3"
                android:label="Dashboard Fragment 3"
                tools:layout="@layout/fragment_3" />
        <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment4"
                android:name="com.example.app.Fragment4"
                android:label="Dashboard Fragment 4"
                tools:layout="@layout/fragment_4" />

    </navigation>

    <navigation
            android:id="@+id/actionProfile"
            android:label="Profile"
            app:startDestination="@id/myProfileFragment">
        <fragment
                android:id="@+id/myProfileFragment"
                android:name="com.example.app.MyProfileFragment"
                android:label="My Profile"
                tools:layout="@layout/fragment_my_profile"/>

        <fragment
                android:id="@+id/editProfileFragment"
                android:name="com.example.app.EditProfileFragment"
                android:label="Edit Profile"
                tools:layout="@layout/fragment_edit_profile"/>

        <action
                android:id="@+id/navigateToEditProfile"
                app:destination="@id/editProfileFragment" />
    </navigation>
</navigation>
```

**Note** the `action` section within `actionProfile`:

```
<action
        android:id="@+id/navigateToEditProfile"
        app:destination="@id/editProfileFragment" />
```

The above is the actual **global action** that you are looking for.

So to put the flow into perspective you would do the following to navigate from `Fragment2` changeAvatar button.

```kotlin
fun navigateToChangeAvatar() {
    changeAvatar.setOnClickListener { view ->
        view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.navigateToEditProfile)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

try with the deep link

Navigation graph.

```
<navigation
 ...>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/editProfileFragment"
        >

        ...
        <deepLink
            android:id="@+id/deepLink"
            app:uri="yourapp://edit/prfile" />
        ...
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

In Fragment.

```
findNavController().navigate(Uri.parse("yourapp://edit/prfile"))
```

Comment: Have you try this, what's happened with the stacks? Can you share more with this solution?

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare your action like this for getting a fragment from your back stack

```
<action
    android:id="@+id/yourActionName"
                 app:destination="@id/editProfileFragment" />
                 app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
                 app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
                 app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
                 app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"
                 app:popUpTo="@+id/editProfileFragment" />
```

Answer (score 2):

To navigate from **Home > Fragment2** to **Profile > EditProfile** you can pass an id by edit type using `Navigation`.

### Fragment2.kt

```
private fun navigateToEditProfileAvatar() {
    buttonEditProfileAvatar.setOnClickListener { button -> 
        Navigation.findNavController(button).navigate(
                R.id.action_global_to_edit_profile,
                RootNavigationDirections.actionGlobalToEditProfile(
                        editType = EditType.EDIT_PROFILE_AVATAR.id
                ).arguments
        )
    }
}
```

### EditProfileFragment.kt

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState) 

    ...

    viewModel.setEditTypeId(EditProfileFragmentArgs.fromBundle(arguments ?: Bundle()).editType)

}

private fun bind() {
    when (viewModel.editTypeId) {
         EditType.EDIT_PROFILE.id -> { ... }
         EditType.EDIT_PROFILE_AVATAR.id -> { 
             // here
         }
    }
}
```

### EditProfileVM.kt

```
val editTypeId = MutableLiveData<String>()
fun setEditTypeId(id: editTypeId ) {...}
```

### res/navigation/root_navigation.xml

```
<action
    android:id="@+id/action_global_to_edit_profile"
    app:destination="@id/edit_profile_fragment" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/edit_profile_fragment"
    android:name="EditProfileFragment"
    android:label=" "
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_edit_profile">

    <argument
        android:name="editType"
        app:argType="string"
        android:defaultValue="@string/edit_profile"
    />

</fragment>
```

### EditType.kt

```
enum class EditType(val id: String) {
    EDIT_PROFILE("EDIT_PROFILE"), EDIT_PROFILE_AVATAR("EDIT_PROFILE_AVATAR");
}
```

*Note*: The arguments of a navigation cannot be of type Enum

GL