# How to navigate with nested navGraph and bottom navigation view

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview, android-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I've bottom nav view with 3 item, My `navGraph` looks like this:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
app:startDestination="@id/nested_navigation"

<navigation
    android:id="@+id/nested_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment" >
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:name="com.example.app.ui.main.MainFragment"
        android:label="main_fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/main_fragment" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:name="com.example.app.ui.main.List"
        android:label="fragment_news_list"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_list" />
</navigation>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/settings"
    android:name="com.example.app.ui.main.Settings"
    android:label="Settings" />
</navigation>
```

The navigation in the bottom navigation view with the nested navGraph fragments work properly, but if I navigate to `settings_fragment`, which is outside the nested navGraph, And I click on the other items/fragments I can't navigate to the other fragments and I basically stuck on this screen.

I checked what happened is if I put the `settings_fragment` inside the nested navGraph, and it's works great.

How can I fix this problem?

btw - I'm pretty sure it's not related, but settings fragment is `PreferenceScreen` layout that sits inside XML resource and not layout resource

My menu items:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/home"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    />
<item
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_format_list_bulleted_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/news_list"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    />
<item
    android:id="@+id/settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/settings"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    />
```

Comment: Why do you need this nested pattern?

Comment: In greneral - The fragments inside the nested navGraph have close relationship and they share viewModel, as shown here - https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#share_ui-related_data_between_destinations_with_viewmodel The middle fragments observe the list that the first fragments gets from network

Answer (score 2):

The issue is to do with the structure of your nav graph.

Bottom navigation will only take into account the root elements.

```sh
- nested_navigation (root element) defaults to `mainFragment`
 |- mainFragment (child element)
 |- list (child element)
- settings (root element)
```

So given the above illustration, you will only be able to make use of the bottom navigation to navigate between `settings` and `nested_navigation` which in turn would be `mainFragment`.

If you were to navigate between `settings` and `list` it would not have been possible.

Please take note that the `id` of the menu items have to match the `id` of the graph destination.

E.g.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/nested_navigation"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/home"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/settings"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

Note the `id` of the two elements match precisely the `id` of the `root` destinations.

**Extra**

Perhaps my other answer may be of help to complement the navigation flow -> [How to switch to other fragment in different back stack using Navigation Component?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61693781/974184)

Comment: I think you are in the right way(I checked whats happen if I specify the nested navGraph id as an item and I do able to navigate), **BUT** -  I actually can navigate to all of my fragments, the only probblem is that I can't navigate to the other fragments, not even to the ```mainFragment``` when I navgiate to ```settings```.  The "problem" with yout answer, that I need each fragment as menu item. with your approach I've only ```mainFragment``` and ```settings``` as menu items

Comment: I understand what you mean but you simply can not do what you want with the existing structure. What you can do is move `<fragment android:id="@+id/list" />` outside of the nested navigation for instance above `settings`.

Answer (score 2):

Bottom navigation will only take into account the root elements.
You can rename the item in menu same as in navigation graph.

EX. Your nested graph name is homeNavigation -> let's name id in menu is homeNavigation.