# BottomNavigationView icons not highlighted with Navigation 2.4

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview, android-navigation-graph

I updated to Navigation 2.4 (`def nav_version = "2.4"`) and now when tapping on a `BottomNavigationView` item it does not always highlight the icon or show the fragment the `BottomNavigationView` item id points to.

There are 3 bottom navigation tabs called `Home`, `Actions`, `My Progress`. From the `Home` fragment, you can navigate to `SubFragment`.

So the flow might be to start at `Home` --> go to `SubFragment` --> go to `Actions` with the `BottomNavigationView` --> and then tap on `Home` to go back. What this did before the update was open the `Home` fragment (desired behavior). Now when tapping on the Home icon it shows `SubFragment` and does not highlight the icon.

[image]

**More details**

This is the navController setup:

```
bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation_view)

val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
val navController = navHostFragment.navController
bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

The `nav_graph` structure is like this:

```
    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:name="com.example.app.home"
            android:label="Home"
            tools:layout="@layout/home" 

            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_home_fragment_to_sub_fragment"
                app:destination="@id/sub_fragment"/>
    </fragment>

    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/subfragment"
            android:name="com.example.app.subfragment"
            android:label="Sub Fragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/subfragment" />

    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/actions"
            android:name="com.example.app.actions"
            android:label="Actions"
            tools:layout="@layout/actions" />

    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/myprogress"
            android:name="com.example.app.myprogress"
            android:label="My Progress"
            tools:layout="@layout/myprogress" />
```

The menu items id's for the `BottomNavigationView` are identical to `nav_graph`.

I thought the issue might be with the `nav_graph` structure not playing well with the new SDK, so I tried adjusting the structure of the `nav_graph` so that each navigation tab was within its own   [like this question answer has setup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61693781/6110783). It highlights the tab with this approach but still does not navigate to `Home` like the example above. Only to `SubFragment`.

Ideas on what I might be missing are appreciated!

Comment: Navigation 2.4 and higher supports [multiple back stacks](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/multiple-back-stacks-b714d974f134), so it would be expected that reselecting the Home tab would restore the whole back stack of that tab (i.e., including your SubFragment).

Comment: @ianhanniballake thanks for chiming in. Are you saying that the default changed and that by re-selecting the Home tab would not go to the Home fragment (i.e. the id BottomNavigationView points to), but to the last fragment in that stack? Is there a simple way to have it so when selecting the Home tab it goes to the Home fragment?

Answer (score 2):

I also came across with this issue. It is not a bug in the library.

Actually, when you link menu.xml with nav_graph.xml
You only specified only one fragmentId for each destination. Therefore, it is natural for icon not to change its current state when subfragment is selected.

Instead, you should use nested navigation graphs and use the id of that graph for menu.xml.

```
<navigation
    android:id="@+id/home_destination"
    app:startDestination="@id/home" >
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:name="com.example.app.home"
        android:label="Home"
        tools:layout="@layout/home" 

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_home_fragment_to_sub_fragment"
            app:destination="@id/sub_fragment"/>
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/subfragment"
        android:name="com.example.app.subfragment"
        android:label="Sub Fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/subfragment" />
</navigation>

<fragment
        android:id="@+id/actions"
        android:name="com.example.app.actions"
        android:label="Actions"
        tools:layout="@layout/actions" />

<fragment
        android:id="@+id/myprogress"
        android:name="com.example.app.myprogress"
        android:label="My Progress"
        tools:layout="@layout/myprogress" />
```

And when you are specifying the navigation_menu you will do like this:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/home_destination"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_read_quran"
    android:title="@string/read_quran"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

Comment: This is the correct answer: "you should use nested navigation graphs and use the id of that graph for menu.xml". Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Haven't figured out a fix for the issue yet, so downgraded to `def nav_version = "2.3.5"` and navigation works properly again.

This is the version before Navigation 2.4 as mentioned by @ ianhanniballake above in comments.